# Unable to connect to VPN, but can connect to the internet

Tags: vpn

I have a client that is trying to access my VPN server from a newly allowed connection at his work place. He can connect to the internet and browse when he plugs in his laptop, but when he tries the VPN connection to my server it does not connect. Any help is appreciated. He has connected to my VPN previously from his home

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What client/server VPN application are you using?  Are there any logs client or server side?  Does your client have a valid credentials for the VPN?

Comment: I'm trying to keep this basic.. Yes, the client has log in credentials. Is it possible that the connection provided to him has restricted outgoing access (in this instance to a VPN server)?

Comment: Sure the computer he's using could block outgoing access to a port.  It's hard to help without details.  There are too many VPN applications, and two many points of failure along the way.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just wanted to be able to point in him in a specific direction.

Comment: @Bob make sure there is no egress filtering on the gateway appliance (firewall / router) in addition to his computer. If there was going to be outgoing filtering, unless it was a locked down laptop from a workplace, the firewall is likely your best place to look. This also assumes that your VPN server has the correct input rules to allow the connections from the IP, and that the client has all the necessary credentials (certificates, pre-shared keys, credentials, etc).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a firewall issue, probably installed by his job's IT team. He should check with them to see if they are filtering it, and if he can get whitelisted.